# java socket permission problem

Tags: java, security, sockets

I have a need to write to a remote machine via a Socket from within an applet.   The applet resides within an intranet within a closed hospital system so changing the java security file is not an issue.    From the Oracle site, they recommend the following policy change:

grant {
  permission java.net.SocketPermission 
  "10.130.71.156:8000", "connect,accept";
};

I have done this but I am still getting the following error:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission [10.130.71.156:8000]resolve)
```

Any ideas of what the problem could be?

Comment: You realize that `puffin.eng.sun.com` is just a demo/placeholder address, right?

Comment: Yes.    That is not what is in my permission file.     I have the actual DNS of the server that I'm trying to connect to.

Comment: Try changing the hostname to the wildcard `*` to ensure it's not confused DNS hostname resolution.

Comment: Are you testing with the appletviewer or a browser? Are you sure the correct policy file is being used?

Comment: Testing with a browser iE 8.    We are sure the correct policy file is being used.      It works with everything else we are doing.     For example, we use it to call a dll and that works.

Comment: Changing to the wildcard worked.    I'm not sure why.    But that was a very useful suggestion.   Thank you,

Comment: Are you sure that perimeter-only security is sufficient for a hospital?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a configuration problem that was causing the error.   The IP address in the config file did not match the IP address in the policy file.   That is why there was the security error.     The person (ataylor) who in their comment recommended using the wildcard deserves the credit for answering this one.   The wildcard allowed us to see what DNS was being polled.   Thank you!

Elliott

Answer (score 2):

The way the question is formulated right now, the SecurityException is thrown since the policy doesn't allow "resolve". The policy should most likely be

grant { permission java.net.SocketPermission "10.130.71.156:8000", "connect,resolve"; };