# Azure java webapp: security manager blocks network access

Tags: azure, tomcat, azure-web-app-service

I have a Azure java webapp and want to connect it to an Oracle database in some VNET via JDBC. The webapp is connected to the VNET via a VPN point to site.
Creating the connection fails.
So I had a look at the logs and found:

> ```
>    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
>    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
>    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:454) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
>    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:446) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
>    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:648) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
>    at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:189) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
>    at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.<init>(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:81) ~[ojdbc8.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
>    at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:169) ~[ojdbc8.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
> ```

So it seems there is a Security Manager running which blocks network access.

I am using the Oracle thin JDBC driver, so no native Libs are involved.
The webapp is 64 Bit Windows. Java is Version 8. I am using the newest Tomcat 8.0 version.

How can I configure it or switch it off? Is it possible to configure this in the WAR file?
I do not think its possible to edit a catalina.policy file, this is a Azure Webapp.

---

It seems this depends on the IP address, if the IP address is in the public internet the connection is made.
But with the 10.*.*.*  non public IP of the database in the VNET the java.net.SocketException is raised. 
Can it be that some network error like "no route to host" or "connection refused" is translated into this SocketException?

Comment: Have you tried add socket permission in java policy file like:`grant { permission java.net.SocketPermission "10...", "connect,resolve"; }`, refer to this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326086/java-socket-permission-problem). And  make sure the IP address you've given your server isn't the [same as another device](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/archive/legacy-support/1820271-solution-internal-client-error-java-net).

Comment: No, this is a Azure Webapp, I think am not able to change the config of the server. I can only configure the webapps. But the cause of the problem was something else, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved this myself.

In the "Point-to-site" configuration, I had the checkbox "IKEv2 VPN" checked.
This must be unchecked. Maybe this is documented somewhere.

How I got there:
I found something about "syncing" for Azure VPN gateways in the internet.

It seems the VPN gateways have to be synced.
This is not possible on the "Virtual Network Integration" tab of the web app.
But it is also possible to configure the network on the "Service Plan" of the webapp.
There is also a Networking section and then there is another VNET Integration section.
Choose your VNET and then you get another "Virtual Network Integration" tab.

But this time there is an additionally "Sync Network" button. Press it. When the
"IKEv2 VPN" option was checked, I got an error which pointed out the bad configuration.